# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType

Tags: python, odoo, nonetype

I am new user in Python, I have a problem with the `None` type, I looked different question, but the problem persists.

My code is looking for Friday and Saturday between two dates, so far it works, but when I sum both I have this error:

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type (s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

After I return the result in the function.

**Here's my code :**

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime
import calendar
calendar.setfirstweekday(calendar.SUNDAY)

from odoo import models, fields, api

class HrMission(models.Model):
    _name = "hr.employee.mission"
    _description = "hr mission"
    _inherit = "hr.employee.mission"

    days_compensation =fields.Float(compute='get_compensation', compstring='Jours de récupération', help="Jours de récupération si la mission contient les jours de repos",
                             required=True, readonly=True,)

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('mission_start_date', 'mission_end_date')
    def get_compensation(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.mission_start_date and rec.mission_end_date:
                time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(rec.mission_start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
                time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(rec.mission_end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
                week = {}
                leave_value = {}
        # Compute Number Of Friday And Saturday
                for i in range((time2 - time1).days):
                    day = calendar.day_name[(time1 + datetime.timedelta(days=i+1)).weekday()]
                    week[day] = week[day] + 1 if day in week else 1                    
                fri = week.get('Friday')  # Result Number 4 Of Friday If "Start Date", "End date" --> "01/01/2017", "31/01/2017"
                sat = week.get('Saturday') # Same thing that friday
                friandsat = mon + sat # Error ---> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'"
                rec.days_compensation = friandsat
```

Comment: Can you show us the error you're getting, along with the stacktrace showing where the error occurs?

Comment: If you're talking about summing results obtained by calling this method, then I'm betting that your problem is that this method does not return a value. - it isn't clear to me what value you should be returning.

Comment: I know, that's the problem and I want to return the value of Fridays and Saturdays but it's NoneType, please help me

Comment: Oh.  Sorry.  I just noticed your comment in the code. It isn't clear to me from your code how you can assume that **week** will contain both the keys **Friday** and **Saturday**.

Comment: You need to provide a more complete example.  Something that we can run, including sample data/input that causes the problem you are seeing.  Please check out [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's the complete code, I inherited a model that contains fields mission_start_date and mission_end_date

Comment: That's not complete code.  Complete code would include code that instantiates a **HrMission** object.  If someone "runs" this code by itself, nothing would happen.  It just defines a class, but doesn't cause anything to actually happen. - Your question is very dependent on data...the dates you're processing.  Where do those come from?  What are the values you're using for testing?  There's a lot you aren't showing us.

Comment: See my answer for one way of turning this into a complete, runnable example

Comment: See my updated answer for a way to have your code never crash with the error message you provided in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- One thing to be careful of, is whether the start and end dates are *both* to be included in the date range. For example, if both dates are `datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1)`, then should the answer be `1`?

```
...
def get_compensation(self):
    def date_range_inclusive(rec):
        # if either date is undefined, then so is date range
        if not rec.mission_end_date or not rec.mission_start_date:
            return iter([])

        # Add 1 for inclusivity of both start and end dates
        num_days = abs((rec.mission_end_date - rec.mission_start_date).days) + 1
        return (rec.mission_start_date + timedelta(days=n) for n in range(num_days))

    for rec in self:
        # date range, including both start and end dates
        dates = date_range_inclusive(rec)
        # desired days to count
        day_selection = (calendar.FRIDAY, calendar.SATURDAY)

        rec.days_compensation = sum([dt.weekday() in day_selection for dt in dates])
```

The above code will assume that the date range is inclusive. Remove `+ 1` to make it not inclusive. It will set the `days_compensation` field to 0 if no Fridays or Saturdays are included.

- Note that there is no need to convert back and forth between data types since both the calendar days enumeration and `weekday` function in `datetime` evaluate to integers that can be compared.
- Another thing to mind, is, according to https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html

`computed fields are not stored by default, they are computed and returned when requested. Setting store=True will store them in the database and automatically enable searching`

Therefore, you might want:

```
days_compensation = fields.Float(compute='get_compensation', compstring='Jours de récupération', help="Jours de récupération si la mission contient les jours de repos", required=True, readonly=True,
store=True)
```

Note the only update was `store=True`

Comment: always the same thing no return, the field `days_compensation` is always `null` when I choose the two dates

Answer (score 0):

I've played with your code.  It seems to kinda work.  It figures out what days of the week exist in a range of dates.  The problem you're seeing occurs when there aren't both a Friday and a Saturday in your range of dates (note that you have a variable named 'mon' that is set by looking for the key 'Friday').

So it seems that your problem is just that you have to allow for the case where you don't have both these days of the week in the range of dates your provide as input.  In that case, either or both of week.get('Friday') and week.get('Saturday') are not going to exist in your **week** map, and so **mon** and/or **sat** are going to be **None**, and you're going to have a problem.

To get your code to run, I added this below it:

```
class Rec:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.mission_start_date = start
        self.mission_end_date = end

self = [
    Rec("2019-3-31", "2019-4-1")
]

get_compensation(self)
```

This lets me cause your code to process a pair of dates.  If the range of dates I give here includes both a Friday and a Saturday, your code runs fine.  Otherwise it barfs with exactly the error you're talking about.

If you change the lines:

```
mon = week.get('Friday')
sat = week.get('Saturday')
```

to:

```
mon = week.get('Friday') if 'Friday' in week else 0
sat = week.get('Saturday') if 'Saturday' in week else 0
```

then your code does not crash for any date ranges I tested it with. I don't know if it's computing the results you want, because you aren't holding onto or returning any of the results of your computations.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "fri" do not "my". It does not sum up between the two variables "fri" and "sat". Please help me, I have spent hours and hours but I have not solved the problem

Comment: I see what you're trying to do.  I see a number of ways of fixing this.  But one thing you can do is check to see if the **Saturday'** key is in your **week** dict.  If not, then you counted 0 saturdays.  Same for Fridays.  One thing you could do is initialize your map so that the map starts with an entry for every day, each with 0 occurrences.  Then the code that is erroring out now would work, because week['Saturday'] would always have a value.

Comment: I think your code might work if you changed the two key lines in question to `fri = week.get('Friday') if 'Friday' in week else 0`, and same for Saturday.

Comment: I updated my answer to include what I just said here.  That seems to fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you ^^,  the problem than I mentioned, is delete but the function does not return anything which concludes that I have value always zero, able in the import of calendar, no!

Comment: Ok.  Not sure exactly what you're saying, but I hope I helped you to get a little further along.  I do think your code is doing some cool stuff with dates.  Please click the checkmark for my answer if you feel I was able to answer your issue with the error you were getting.  This isn't about me getting points.  It's about keeping S.O. questions properly annotated so the next reader knows what's goinog on.  If you want more help, I would suggest opening a new question.

Comment: I know very well what I say haha, brief the problem now is to return the result (a number of days of Friday and Saturday between two dates)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can return Fridays and Saturdays between two dates by using `datetime` format. That is all. And a condition to check if the day name is the required one or not.

This format prints the day name: `"%A"`

Answer (score 0):

This is for someone arriving here from search engines. **I faced this error while importing data.** This happened because I had the product id field mapped to `Product` instead of `Product/External ID`. So if you got this error while importing data, check whether the id fields are mapped properly.